# How to change label of rotation button in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

The documentation claims that "instead of text also an element (e.g. span) can be used":
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Rotate.html

I tried

```js
this.olMap = new Map({
  // replace arrow with compass icon on rotation button
  controls: defaultControls({
    rotateOptions: {
      autoHide: false,
      className: 'my-compass',
      label: '<svg class="ol-compass compass-svg block w-5 h-5 cursor-pointer select-none z-120" role="button" aria-label="Compass"><use xlink:href="#compass" /></svg>',
      tipLabel: 'Reset GeoMover Rotation'
    }
  }),
[...]
```

However, that does not work. Neither does using the class name "compass-svg" or simply the  tag.
What is the proper use of label with a svg element?

UPDATE:

In addition to the accepted solution, I'd like to add an example for incorporating a "use" fragment with svg, which needs special care when generated with Javascript (see https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/svg-use-element-javascript-4513/):

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- A svg element that only "collects" symbols: -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <def>
    <!-- This fragment shall be used for the rotate button -->
    <symbol id="compass" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g clip-path="url(#clip0)"><path fill="currentColor" d="M10.98 2.19L7.5 11.48a2 2 0 000 1.4l3.47 9.29a1.24 1.24 0 002.31 0l3.47-9.3a2 2 0 000-1.39l-3.47-9.3a1.24 1.24 0 00-2.31 0zm3.15 9.99a2 2 0 11-3.99 0 2 2 0 014 0z"/></g><defs><clipPath id="clip0"><path fill="#fff" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/></clipPath></defs></symbol>
  </def>
</svg>
```

```js
// JavaScript

// function that returns the svg element
compassIcon () {
  const svgElem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
  const useElem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use')

  svgElem.setAttribute('role', 'button')
  svgElem.setAttribute('aria-label', 'compass')
  svgElem.classList.add('ol-compass', 'compass-svg')

  // `#compass` is the id of the svg symbol
  useElem.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#compass')
  svgElem.appendChild(useElem)

  return svgElem
}

// Usage with OpenLayers in Vue
export default {
   data: () => ({
      olMap: null,
   }),
   mounted() {
      this.olMap = new Map({
          // add rotate functionality
          interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new DragRotateAndZoom()]),
          // change rotate button
          controls: defaultControls({
              rotateOptions: {
                  autoHide: false,
                  label: this.compassIcon()
              }
          }),
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It must be an element, not a text string, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/rotation-forked-pmgb2?file=/main.js

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your quick response! Awesome! (IMO this should go into the documentation!) - Can I motivate you to post your comment as a real answer, so I can upvote and accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string will be treated as label text, so an element must be used, which would usually be created using `createElement()`.  If a span element is used an image can defined inside that by setting its `innnerHTML` property, for example

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = '<img src="compass.png">';

var map = new Map({
  controls: defaultControls({
    rotateOptions: { label: span }
  }),
  ...
  ...
});
```